# NoSQL or SQL or Other Tools for scaling excel spreadsheets

Tags: sql, excel, nosql, business-intelligence

I am looking to convert an excel spreadsheet into more of a scalable solution for reporting. The volume of the data is not very large. At the moment the spreadsheet around 5k rows and grows by about 10 every day. There are also semi-frequent changes in how we capture information i.e. new columns as we starting to mature the processes. The spreadsheet just stores attributes or dimensions data on cases.

I am just unsure whether I should use a traditional SQL database or NoSQL database (or any other tool). I have no experience in NoSQL but I understand that it is designed to be very flexible which is what I want compared to a traditional DB.

Any thoughts would be appreciated :) !

Comment: Curious about what the business needs are in terms of "flexibility" -- whether you are using NOSQL or SQL, when the schema/design of the excel sheet changes you will have to change something somewhere to use/consider those changes, so whether you are making SQL schema changes or changes to the app that uses this database... not sure that it makes much of a difference. What are you going to do with the data once it's in the database?

Comment: Easier search+ analysis and reporting

Answer (score 1):

Your dataset is really small and any SQL database (say, PostgreSQL) will work just fine. Stay away from NoSQL DBs as they are more limited in terms of reporting capability.

However, since your facts schema is still not stable ("new columns as we starting to mature the processes.") you may simply use your Spreadsheet as a data source in BI tools. To keep your reports up-to-date you may use the following process:

- Store your Spreadsheet on cloud storage (like Google Drive or OneDrive)
- Use codeless automation platform (like Zapier) to setup a job to sync Spreadsheet file with BI tool when it changes. This is easily possible if BI tool is SeekTable, for instance.